# Errno 111 Connection refused Django REST on CPanel

Tags: django, email, smtp, connection, cpanel

I'm using gmail smtp, and I get this error:
[Errno 111] Connection refused

I'm getting this on cpanel shared hosting, but it's working perfectly fine on local.

Here's my Django configuration:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = config("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_FROM = config("EMAIL_FROM")
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'email@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BCC = ""
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

I contacted my WHM and told them to disable smtp restrictions. Their firewall is also not blocking gmail's smtp and the required ports are also open.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by telling my WHM to add my cPanel username on SMTP_ALLOWUSER as per: [SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) with Office365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318878/smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server-connection-refused-111-with-office365)